# Liferay-dxp configuration on weblogic 12c

Tags: java, weblogic, liferay

How to configure liferay-dxp (sp1) in weblogic 12c ?

Please find detail log .

14:53:58,877 ERROR [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'][SPATopHeadJSPDynamicInclude:47] Unable to include JSP /init.jsp
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException

14:53:58,886 ERROR [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'][DynamicIncludeUtil:79] java.io.IOException: Unable to include JSP /init.jsp

Comment: What have you done so far? Are these errors the result of a default configuration?

Comment: The issue has been resolved in Liferay-DXP-sp3 . Ref. https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPE-15750

Comment: Post that as the answer to your own question so that people will recognize that is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been resolved in Liferay-DXP-sp3 . Ref. http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPE-15750